# How do I add a class to a Selectize option, dynamically?

Tags: jquery, css, selectize.js

When adding options to a `select` input, it's trivial to conditionally add a class, using jQuery:

```
$("#mySelect").append(
    $("<option></option>") 
        .text(myName)
        .val(myValue)
        .addClass(myBoolean ? "class1" : "class2")
);
```

My question is: how can I achieve the same effect using *selectize.js*?

I can use the following code to add an option (the variable `mySelect` refers to something like `$("#mySelect")[0].selectize`).

```
mySelect.addOption({
    value: productGrouping.id,
    text:  productGrouping.name
});
```

Adding a `class` option here doesn't work, and `addOption()` doesn't return anything, so I'm stuck as to how to do this. Is is possible?

Comment: Have you instantiated the selectize plugin? Something like: `var $select = $('#mySelect').selectize(options);`

Comment: I have indeed, yup. The dropdown displays fine... I just want to be able to add a class to options. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an excellent case for a [SelectizeJS Plugin](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/plugins.md).

I wrote up one that is a simple example of what I think you want -- options marked with a "favorite: true" property have a new class, and style, added to them dynamically in the SelectizeJS widget.

**selectize.plugins.js**

```
Selectize.define('favorite_options', function(options) {
  options = $.extend({
        className : 'favorited'
    }, options);

  var favoriteOptionsClass = function(thisRef, options) {

    var self = thisRef;
    console.log({'self':self})

    var original = self.setup;
    self.setup = (function() {

        return function() {

          var option_render = self.settings.render.option;
          self.settings.render.option = function(option) {
            // "render" the original option to get the current HTML
            var html = option_render.apply(self, arguments);

            // modify HTML to add class
            var $html = $(html);
            var classes = $html.attr("class");

            if (option.favorite) {
              $html.addClass("favorite")
            }

            // return NEW $html element as HTML string
            return $('<div>').append($html.clone()).html();
          }

          original.apply(self, arguments);
        };
    })();
  }

  favoriteOptionsClass(this, options);
  return;
});
```

**app.js**

```
$("#wiki-select-property").selectize({
  maxItems: 1,
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'title',
    searchField: 'title',
    plugins: [
      'favorite_options' 
    ],
    options: [
        {id: 1, title: 'Spectrometer', favorite: true, url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrometers'},
        {id: 2, title: 'Star Chart', favorite: false,  url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_chart'},
        {id: 3, title: 'Electrical Tape', favorite: false,  url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_tape'}
    ]
})
```

[Working Plnkr Example](http://embed.plnkr.co/dhBImkOPzUqBxXo25aK2/)